# How to join array of optional integers to string?

Tags: arrays, swift, functional-programming, option-type

Given [Int?], need to build string from it.

This code snippet works

```
    let optionalInt1: Int? = 1
    let optionalInt2: Int? = nil

    let unwrappedStrings = [optionalInt1, optionalInt2].flatMap({ $0 }).map({ String($0) })
    let string = unwrappedStrings.joined(separator: ",")
```

But I don't like `flatMap` followed by `map`. Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another approach:

```
[optionalInt1, optionalInt2].flatMap { $0 == nil ? nil : String($0!) }
```

Edit: You probably shouldn't do this. These approaches are better, to avoid the `!`

```
[optionalInt1, optionalInt2].flatMap {
    guard let num = $0 else { return nil }
    return String(num)
}
```

or:

```
[optionalInt1, optionalInt2].flatMap { $0.map(String.init) }
```

Comment: This solution will also work where the generic type of the array doesn't conform to `CustomStringConvertible` or doesn't have a `description` property.

Comment: @YakivKovalskiy in this case it's very apparent that `$0` is `.some(...)` if the 2nd conditional target of the ternary operator is entered; a special case where we truly may use `!` safely and at the same time showing, semantically, that we know what we're doing.

Comment: @YakivKovalskiy Forced unwrapping isn't necessarily bad. It's way overused and abused, but it's perfectly justifiable in a case like this

Comment: @Alexander you may be right. In my opinion, one should never ever use force unwrap in Swift code, but this topic is too controversial to discuss here.

Comment: @YakivKovalskiy *never* is a pretty strong statement, there are multiple places where there really isn't any other choice, such as for recursive closure definitions

Comment: `flatMap` has been replaced with `compactMap`.

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of the [`map` method of `Optional`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optional/1539476-map) within a `flatMap` closure applied to the array, making use of the fact that the former will return `nil` without entering the supplied closure in case the optional itself is `nil`:

```
let unwrappedStrings = [optionalInt1, optionalInt2]
    .flatMap { $0.map(String.init) }
```

---

Also, if you don't wrap the trailing closures (of `flatMap`, `map`) in paranthesis and furthermore make use of the fact that the initializer reference `String.init` will (in this case) non-ambigously resolve to the correct `String` initializer (as used above), a chained `flatMap` and `map` needn't look "bloated", and is also a fully valid approach here (the chained `flatMap` and `map` also hold value for semantics).

```
let unwrappedStrings = [optionalInt1, optionalInt2]
    .flatMap{ $0 }.map(String.init)
```

Comment: But I'm trying to avoid use of `map` and `flatMap` methods here because loop through array twice can't be good.

Comment: @YakivKovalskiy note that the first solution above use the `map` operation of the _optional type_ (which is a single call to an instance method of the optional element), not of the array, so there will only be one pass over the array in that one. The first method above is almost equivalent to [@Alexander's solution below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41489590/4573247). Nonetheless, a chained `flatMap` and `map` is still `O(n)`, and I don't see how this could ever be _"can't be good"_ unless you're working with some extremely heavy HPC application. If not, put likewise focus also on semantics.

Comment: @YakivKovalsky If you want to avoid repeated looping, use `.lazy`. E.g. `array.map(fn1).map(fn2)` will only read the elements once, applying each function in succession directly, without copying/storing intermediate results into intermediate arrays.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like the `flatMap` and the `map` together you can replace this

```
[optionalInt1, optionalInt2].flatMap({ $0 }).map({ String($0) })
```

with this

```
[optionalInt1, optionalInt2].flatMap { $0?.description }
```

### Wrap up

```
let optionalInt1: Int? = 1
let optionalInt2: Int? = nil

let result = [optionalInt1, optionalInt2]
    .flatMap { $0?.description }
    .joined(separator: ",")
```

### Update

Since:

- as *@Hamish* pointed out direct access to `description` is discouraged by the Swift team
- and the OP wants to avoid the `flatMap` + `map` concatenation because of the double loop

I propose another solution

```
let result = [optionalInt1, optionalInt2].flatMap {
        guard let num = $0 else { return nil }
        return String(num)
    }.joined(separator: ",")
```

Comment: Nice catch! I forgot about `.description` trying to make things work with `String(describing:)`, `String()`

Comment: Note that the Swift team discourages you from directly accessing the `description` property (last paragraph of the Overview [in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/customstringconvertible)) – although I admit it allows for a nice looking call.

Comment: @Hamish: I didn't know that. Thank you very much for the information.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers use `flatMap` to eliminate the `nil` elements and require a call to `joined()` to combine the elements and add the commas.

Using `joined()` to add the commas is of course a second pass through the
array.  Here's a way to use `reduce` to do this in one pass:

```
let arr: [Int?] = [nil, nil, 1, 2, 3, nil, 4, nil, 5, nil]

let result = arr.reduce("") { $1 == nil ? $0 : $0.isEmpty ? "\($1!)" : $0 + ",\($1!)" }

print(result)
```

Output:

> ```
> 1,2,3,4,5
> ```

---

**Explanation**

This example uses `reduce` to construct the result string element by element.

`reduce` is a method called on a sequence.  It takes an initial value (`""` in this example) and a closure that combines the next element in the sequence with the partial result to create the next partial result.

The closure is called on each element in the sequence (i.e. array `arr`).  The closure first checks if the element is `nil` and if it is, it returns the partial result unmodified.  If the element is not `nil`, it then checks if the partial result is still the empty string.  If it is empty, this is the first element in the result so it returns a string made up of just the element.  If the partial result is not empty, it adds the new element preceded by a `,` to the partial result.

---

## Use `reduce(into:)`:

Rewriting this to use `reduce(into:)` and `append` results in an implementation that is twice as fast as the other answers when generating the final comma separated string.

```
let result = arr.reduce(into: "") { (string, elem) in
    guard let elem = elem else { return }
    if string.isEmpty {
        string = String(elem)
    } else {
        string.append(",\(elem)")
    }
}
```

Comment: (I'm aware this is an old answer) This has `O(n^2)` time complexity (each append would cause a string duplication), which isn't great. Plus, since the code is more complex than `flatMap` + `joined(separator: " ")`, I would strongly advise against it. See https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Don't%20abuse%20reduce.md

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, in a Release build a 10,000 element array with 10% `nil`s took `0.01` seconds both with my answer and your latest one with `joined(separator: ",")`.  Rewriting to use `reduce(into:)` and `append` ran twice as fast.  So your complaint about the complexity of the code is valid, but the speed concern is unwarranted.

Comment: My performance concerns these days usually are less about time (except for blocking network calls, those are still a big no-no), but more about battery life. I wouldn't put much time into it, but if it's trivial (e.g. put a `.lazy` before a chain of calls), I'd do it up-front, just to keep the device from needing to use its higher-clocked cores and such.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, adding `.lazy` to make `let result = arr.lazy.compactMap { $0.map(String.init) }.joined(separator: ",")` slowed it down from `0.01068` seconds to `0.01469` seconds.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, yes, it is a release build.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.1:

```
[1,2,3].flatMap({String(describing: $0)}).joined(separator: " ")

// "1 2 3" (without quotes sure)
```

Comment: This produces string values of `Optional(1)` and `nil`, which is almost certainly not intended. And even if it *was* intended, that's probably worth strong reconsideration.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding flatMap and map altogether. However creating a local var.

```
let optionalInt1: Int? = 1
let optionalInt2: Int? = nil
let optionalInts = [optionalInt1, optionalInt2]

var strings = [String]()
for optInt in optionalInts {
    if let integer = optInt {
        strings.append(String(integer))
    }
}
let string = strings.joined(separator: ",")
```

Comment: "Avoiding flatMap and map altogether" don't do that.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica May I know why?

Comment: Your entire `for` loop is just a really long way of saying `flatMap` (now called `compactMap`, for this variant). Why reinvent the wheel?